# Ubuntu 16.04 new home partition

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, gparted

Recently I dual booted Ubuntu 16.04 (xenial) alongside Windows 10 on my Dell Inspiron 5547.

I wanted to expand my Ubuntu partition, and prepared unallocated space but my Ubuntu ext4 partition is on the far right, and after reading some other posts I decided not to move Ubuntu boot partition to the left, instead make new `/home` on a new partition (if it was on the left then I could simply resize to the right in that unallocated space).

The problem is I already have 4 primary partitions, MBR is limited only to 4 partitions.

Here are some screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Maybe I should delete DELLUTILITY?

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to create a logical partition. It still work as expected. If you really must use primary partition you'll have to switch to a GPT partition table.

You can read [this](https://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/mbr2gpt.html) article about converting from one partition table to another.

Before you carry out any conversions, remember to back up your data.

Comment: Thanks for your effort, i really don't want to play with these conversions, it seems too dangerous for me.. is there any other way of making logical partition without touching any of my four primary p,? 

D